# Accessing URL Parameters react doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, hyperlink

I am trying to display h2 events on my page and when I click on URL category_events and notations too.

`App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
// import Header from './components/Header';
import Events from './components/Events/Events';
import Date from './components/Date/Date';
import Accueil from './components/Accueil/Accueil';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Link } from 'react-router-dom';




function App() {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <h1>Marine Mammals</h1>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/events">Events</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/date">Date</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/accueil">Accueil</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/events/Category_events">Category Events</Link> 
       </li>
        <li><Link to="/events/Notations">Notations</Link></li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
    <Routes> 
    <Route path="/Date"> <Date/> </Route> 
    <Route exact 
     path="/events"> <Events/> </Route> 
    <Route path="/events/:type"> 
    <Events/> </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>

    </div>
  );
}



export default App;
```

Events.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import Category_events from './Category_events';
import Notations from './Notations';


export default function Events(){
  const { type } = useParams();

  


  return (
    <>
      <h2>Events</h2>
      {type === 'Category_events' && <Category_events />}
      {type === 'Notations' && <Notations/>}

      
    </>
  );
}
```

I got this error:
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /home/thibaut/fastmeet/src/App.js: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <Routes>. (35:8)

33 |         <Route path="/Date"/>
34 |         <Date/>

> 35 |         </Route>
> |         ^
> 36 |
> 37 |         <Route exact path="/events"/>
> 38 |           <Events/>

Comment: You have a terminating slash at the end of your double quotes, closing your HTML tag.  Then you are closing it again with </Route>.  I didn't look too hard if there was anything else wrong but hopefully this gets you moving forward.  You also have it in your other <Route> tags after events and type.  Also type I think you meant a colon and not a semicolon for a param.

Comment: thank you I changed tag <Route> and ; by :        I got now a blank page:  <Routes>
        <Route path="/Date">   
        <Date/>
        </Route>   
        <Route exact path="/events">  
          <Events/>
          </Route> 
        <Route path="/events/:type">  
           <Events/>
          </Route>   </Routes>. Sorry I don't know if I can put my code here?

Comment: @ThibautSlk Edit your question instead of posting a comment.

Comment: thanks. I edited my question. I got a blank page